# How to get 'name' in event [Autocomplete] component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i have handler *fn* for handle input from Textfield.

I want use it fn for autocomplete component, but i cant get 'name' and value from it.

```
function handlerChange(e){ 
const { name, value, checked } = e.target;
  return { name, value: value || checked };
}

 <Autocomplete
    id="distributions"
    name="defaultDistr"
    options={distributions}
    getOptionLabel={distribution => distribution}
    inputValue={defaultDistr}
    defaultValue={defaultDistr}
    onChange={(e, value) => {
      console.log('e', e, 'value', value);
    }}
    renderInput={params => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        name="defaultDistr"
        label="distributions"
        margin="normal"
        fullWidth
      />
    )}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Autocomplete`, there are many different events that can cause changes to the value. There are several different elements from which those events can come from, so you cannot rely on the target of the event to get the name. Similarly the target of the event does not necessarily have a value and even if it does, that value may not represent the current value of the `Autocomplete`. This is why the correct value is passed as a second parameter to your `onChange` handler.

Assuming there is more significant code in `handlerChange` than what you've shown such that it is worth trying to reuse, you can do something like shown below which creates a new object organizing the information into the structure the handler is expecting.

```
<Autocomplete onChange={(event, value)=> { handlerChange({target: {name: "defaultDistr", value: value}})} .../>
```